# Configure ejabberd

Tags: configuration, ejabberd

I was running this command sudo apt-get install ejabberd

But it throws me this error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: ejabberd : Depends:
>   erlang-abi-15.b E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

I'm very new to ejabberd, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your package is probably very old and rely on a old version of Erlang.
You should download package or installer from ProcessOne website. It comes packaged with Erlang and everything is up to date.

Downloads are available on this page: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Comment: i want to configure it on linode server. Can you provide me terminal comands for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple to compile ejabberd + erlang. I suggest to use source code compilation instead of OS shaped packages.

First, download desired ejabberd version and check README file to get actual version of erlang.

Then download and compile erlang to needed destination.
After that you are ready to install ejabberd itself.